# How to define the time-range for the Time Field in Webform 4.x

Tags: webforms

is it possible to change the selectable time range in a time-field in Webform? I don't want the users to have the choice to select between 00:00 and 23:59. I only want them to choose between 15:00 and 23:00.

[Webform validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) doesn't work on time fields. Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with [Clientside Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) Module. Otherwise you can alter the webform to add validation.

You may refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785882/how-do-i-apply-webform-validation-in-drupal-7 link for a reference.